# Android - entries in dialog should be deleted when dialog is closed

Tags: android, dialog, customdialog

I have a customDialog with input fields. I want possible entries to be removed once the dialog is closed (either via back or when a certain button is pressed), i.e. the state should not be saved.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the back button is pressed means that dialog is `canceled`. Implement `DialogInterface.OnCancelListener` for your dialog and empty/delete/null the entries you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be getting another problem.

Say that you have shown a dialog which was dismissed. If the same dialog is going to be shown a second time, it won't be rebuilt. It will just be shown again.

This means that if you setup your dialog in the `onCreateDialog` method, the second time that the dialog is shown, this method isn't invoked! Instead, `onPrepareDialog` is invoked.

Alternatives? You can call `Activity.removeDialog` or take care of the setup process in the `onPrepareDialog` hook.

Comment: What about implementing a onCancelListener, as he asked he needs to empty the entries done in the dialog, since back button/negative button will try to dismiss the dialog, so the dialog is canceled, so inside he can empty the entries. Right? Reasonable?

Comment: If the user presses "Ok" (assuming such button exists)  won't invoke onCancel. I think this could be done in onDismiss, but at that time he wouldn't know which information he should put on the dialog to show the next time...

Comment: He said that entries are emptied/deleteded/null-ed if the dialog is closed. And we speak about that scenario. If we talk about the `OK` button according to previous scenario we can derive conclusion that there is no need to empty/delete the entries.

Comment: Ok, in that case it's possible, but I was suspecting that he would have the problem I described as soon as he would make a move